# Seeking information on the largest Craft sites built

Tags: craft-pro

We're writing an article on the largest Craft sites built and I'm having some challenges finding this information. Ideally, we want to compile a list of the top 20. "Largest" is determined by certain criteria like: Traffic (uniques/month; and pages/month); Number of Entries, Number of Members; Number of forum posts, etc.

I came across this article https://straightupcraft.com/articles/who-uses-craft-cms as a start to find out some basic info on sites built in Craft but it doesn't provide me with any info that would suggest these are some of the largest sites. In fact, when I entered in some of the names from that list into Alexa https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo their global ranking was quite low. I'm seeking help on how to surface this info.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange is generally for more technical questions, so you might not get many replies here.

Have you contacted the folks at Pixel & Tonic directly?

You could also join the [Craft CMS Slack](https://craftcms.com/community#slack). Plenty of developers hang out on there that might not look here, so it'd be worth your while asking the same question there.